# Reference for "every foliation satisfies a system of PDEs"?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, vector-bundles, foliations

I know [foliations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) as a particular topic in differential geometry. I understand the definition and basic properties of a foliation from the DG point of view, including the Frobenius theorem. While trying to understand why this concept is important I came across [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrability_conditions_for_differential_systems) on integrability conditions for differential systems, but couldn't understand much of it. I do not want to too diverge from my other studies now, yet want to understand this association quickly and completely.

Can you suggest me a source that is solely focused on the relation between foliations and systems of PDEs?

Comment: Hmm, so when you say you understand foliations in DG and want to understand that page quickly and completely... I'm guessing you are looking for more than Section 19 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds? The citations on that particular wiki page are by themselves (mostly) excellent.